# How can i find the Correct String or 3 Most Similar Strings from a List using a String?

Tags: python, string, match, similarity, difflib

Trying to find 3 closest matches with a given string like "_e_ul" and the correct match from my list would be Mehul, but `difflib.get_close_matches` seems to be getting very weird matches that don't match my word at all and look very random.

Also if this helps at all, I have a list with all the Possible Strings so the String I am given will surely be in the List. I need some library that can match the positions of the alphabets shown in the string with that of the list.

````
res = get_close_matches(hint,pokemons,n=3,cutoff= 0.2)
    if res == []:
        print("No Similar Names Found Unfortunately")
    else:
        var = "\n".join(res)
        print(f"**Did you Mean...**\n`{var}`")```

hint was _ar__n_e - answer supposed to be mareanie
pokemons is a list containing all pokemon names
The output came out to be 
**Did you Mean...**
`Cacturne
Carnivine
Charmander`
````

Comment: Try using a regex

Comment: It'd be much easier for us to provide any help if you included a minimal working example that shows how you're using the package and how it fails. What are the seemingly random matches for instance?

Comment: @frippe edited in main post

Comment: As far as I can tell, the documentation doesn't say which algorithm is used, nor does it mention any type of wildcard. So, it seems probable that the function does not interpret the underscores as a sort of wildcard, but as actual characters that are included in the computation of the match score.

Comment: @frippe So what else could I possibly use?

Comment: Regex is one option. Otherwise you could check out the other libs that include functionality for word similarity and see if any of them includes wildcard support. Google is your friend here. You could also implement your own algorithm that treats `_` the way you want